# Monotonic equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, monotone-functions

I have some equations like this:

`q1 = u1 * h1`   ,   `q2 = u2 * h2`   ,   `q3 = u3 * h3` (note that `u1`, `u2`, and `u3` can either be positive or negative, but `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` are always positive).

**REVISION**

1. If it always fulfills `min(q3,q1) <= q2 <= max(q3,q1)` and `min(h3,h1) <= h2 <= max(h3,h1)`, it **DOES NOT** always satisfy `min(u3,u1) <= u2 <= max(u3,u1)`. Right? Why? Any proof?
2. If it always fulfills `min(u3,u1) <= u2 <= max(u3,u1)` and `min(h3,h1) <= h2 <= max(h3,h1)`, it **ALWAYS** satisfies `min(q3,q1) <= q2 <= max(q3,q1)`. Right?

Many thanks.

PS: Please don't forget to consider the functions `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the point of the original answer. The moment I break on side of the double inequality I break the whole inequality. I'm not sure why you want that much for a false fact to be a true one but it is still false nevertheless. You can't make any prediction in either of those two cases. Here are two examples (extension to me original ones) to show that the non-obvious cases are still possible:

**Example #1:**

```
u1 = 9, h1 = 10, q1 = 90
u2 = 2, h2 = 55, q2 = 110
u3 = 10, h3 = 60, q3 = 600
```

It is true that

```
h1 < h2 < h3
q1 < q2 < q3
```

but still `u2` is the smallest:

```
u2 < u1 < u3
```

**Example #2:**

```
u1 = -2, h1 = 3, q1 = -6
u2 = -1, h2 = 8, q2 = -8
u3 = 3, h3 = 10, q3 = 30
```

It is true that

```
h1 < h2 < h3
u1 < u2 < u3
```

but still `q2` is the smallest

```
q2 < q1 < q3
```

---

**Original Answer**

I don't know why you use 3 triplets and 2 inequalities, it is enough to have 2 triplets and 1 inequality (the other one is exactly the same). So we know that:

```
q1 = u1 * h1
q2 = u2 * h2
```

and

```
0 <= h2 <= h1
```

**Statement #1.**

Given that you also know that `q2 <= q1`, can you say anything about whether `u1 >= u2` or `u1 <= u2`? The answer is "no, you can't". To prove that something is not always true it is enough to provide one counter example.

Example #1.1

```
q1 = 110 = 2 * 55 = u1 * h1
q2 = 90 = 9 * 10 = u2 * h2
```

Clearly

```
q2 = 90 < 110 = q1
h2 = 10 < 55 = h1
```

but

```
u2 = 9 > 2 = u1
```

Example #1.2

```
q1 = 110 = 11 * 10 = u1 * h1
q2 = 90 = 9 * 10 = u2 * h2
```

Clearly

```
q2 = 90 < 110 = q1
h2 = 10 < 11 = h1
```

and

```
u2 = 9 < 10 = u1
```

So both cases are possible

**Statement #2.**

Given that you know that `u2 <= u1` but both of `u`s can be negative, can you say anything about whether `u1 >= u2` or `u1 <= u2`? The answer is again "no, you can't".

Example #1.2 from the previous section says that the case  when `u2 <= u1`, `h2 <= h1` and `q2 <= q1` is possible which is not a big surprise. An example for other possibility must use negative values for `u`. The intuition behind this example is that if you multiply a big positive number by something negative you get a big negative number which actually means it is a small number comparing to other negative numbers.

Example #2.1

```
q1 = -6 = -2 * 3 = u1 * h1
q2 = -8 = -1 * 8 = u2 * h2
```

Clearly

```
h1 = 3 < 8 = h2
u1 = -2 < -1 = u2
```

but

```
q1 = -6 >  -8 = q2
```

So again both cases are possible.

If we additionally knew that `0 <= u2 <= u1`, then we could say that `q2 <= q1`.  Consider `q2 - q1`:

```
q2 - q1 = u2*h2 - u1*h1 = (u1 + (u2-u1))*(h1 + (h2-h1)) - u1*h1 = 
  =  u1*h1 + (u2-u1)*h1 + (u2-u1)*(h2-h1) + u1*(h2-h1) - u1*h1 =
  =  (u2-u1)*h1 + (u2-u1)*(h2-h1) + u1*(h2-h1) >= 0
```

Obviously if `h1 >= 0` and `u1 >= 0`, all three terms in the last line are non-negative, so `q2 - q1` is non-negative or `q2 >= q1`.

Comment: Apologize I forgot to mention, see the revision. Can you please edit your answer, so that I can vote it? Thanks!

Comment: @bob.bob.bob I still insist that 2 inequalities do not add any new information. If I break one inequality, I break both. I've extended my examples to show that.

Comment: Many thanks. So for the point 1: Is it correct to say: IT DOES NOT ALWAYS GUARANTEE, right? Have you also considered the MIN and MAX functions for the boundary conditions? Thanks.

Comment: @bob.bob.bob, do you see that my counter-examples break the `min` and `max` boundaries as well (just because everything with index `1` is the `min` and with index `3` is the `max` except for the "conclusion" which I break)? If no, then please clarify what do you mean? Please check all your statements against those 2 examples. If one of those examples breaks the statement, don't ask about it again - it is already false and you know it.